# How to send data using api.post?

Tags: reactjs, api, backend

Im not very familiar with ReactJs so I need help. Im working on a form for users to fill up and press submit. In one of my fucntional components (which is working) I can get it to send to the database whereas the class component cannot. I dont which part i am doing wrong.The code is:

```
// Some js file that is working
const InitForm = {
  name : '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
  message: ''
}

function ContactUs({}) {
   const [Form, setForm] = useState(InitForm);
   const {name, email, phone, message} = Form
   await api.post(`/contactus/createContactForm`, {data: Form});
}

//Another js file that is not working
class ContactUsDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            phone: '',
            message: ''
        }
    }

    await api.post(`/contactus/createContactForm`, {data: this.state});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it by wrapping the API call in one of the life cycle methods. In your current code, it is never being called.

```
class ContactUsDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      message: ''
    }

    api.post(`/contactus/createContactForm`, {data: this.state});
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example maybe? I thought the code on top is already wrapped like you said

Comment: Also note, that you are using `await` keywords outside `async` functions. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function async. make it `async function ContactUs({}) {` ...

Also how are you calling the method?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that they are in 2 different files, i updated the post, please see again

Comment: How are you calling the ContactUS function? On button click? Please post all the code